# Why are functional calculi interesting?

Tags: operator-algebras, spectral-theory, functional-calculus

In my class on spectral theory we have defined the continuous functional calculus for normal elements of a C*-algebra. We were told that this is one of the most important results in spectral theory on C*-algebras, but I don't see why it is that important.

Comment: You'll need it in many theorems. Everytime you need a square root of an element or the absolute value, the continuous functional calculus will be used.
You also need it for the existence of approximate units.

Comment: For instance, try to prove that $a,b \geq 0$ implies $a+b \geq 0$.